# Как сделать страницу авторизации php без базы данных?

Tags: php

Как сделать страницу авторизации php без базы данных, чтобы все пароли хранились в текстовом документе на сервере + после авторизации направляло на другую страницу?

Comment: А в чём проблема?

Comment: очень лекго, несколько строк кода.

Comment: только попыток что-то сделать от автора не видно

Comment: Открыть редактор, написать код, залить на сервер. PROFIT!

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать авторизацию срадствами apache а именно htaccess
Сгенерировать htpasswd можно тут: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Код должен получиться что-то вроде этого:

1
Admin:$apr1$Kquu91ma$z8zPO8AoWxNYuuARi3Kgp0
После того как файл htpasswd создан, необходимо прописать кое-какие настройки в файле .htaccess. Файл htaccess должен находиться в директории, для которой нужна авторизация. Авторизация распространяется на все вложенные директории и файлы, поместив файл в корень сайта, мы можем ограничить доступ ко всему сайту.

Параметры в файле htaccess:

1
2
3
4
AuthType Basic
AuthName "want to enter?"
AuthUserFile /home/data/yournet.kz/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Comment: Параметры в файле htaccess:

1
2
3
4
AuthType Basic
AuthName "want to enter?"
AuthUserFile /home/data/yournet.kz/.htpasswd
Require valid-user